# What does the name of the unix command apropos mean?

Tags: man, terminology

[Apropos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apropos_%28Unix%29) is a tool to search the headers of the man pages for a string.

What does the name **apropos** mean?

Comment: I would suggest visiting [this question over on the English Language stack exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9969/3820) - but @Maciej covered it anyway.

Comment: I was going to suggest asking this question to google, but whatever B-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ap·ro·pos
>
> /ˌæprəˈpoʊ/ Show Spelled[ap-ruh-poh] Show IPA
>   –adverb
>
> 1.
>   fitting; at the right time; to the purpose; opportunely.
>
> 2.
>   Obsolete. By the way. –adjective
>
> 3.
>       opportune; pertinent: apropos remarks.
>       —Idiom
>
> 4.
>       apropos of, with reference to; in respect or regard to: apropos of the preceding statement.

Definition #4 is where the unix command stems from.  The results returned are *in reference to* the input argument.

Answer (score 10):

I always thought it is from [à propos](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_propos) meaning "in connection, concerning, with regard, in reference".

**Edit**: Apparently there is also word apropos and à propos meaning the same which are derived from French à propos.

Comment: English is a thief of words, but it has good taste :)

Answer (score 4):

On my system, **[`dict`](http://www.dict.org/w/software/software)`apropos`** tells me:

```
2 definitions found

From The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48 [gcide]:

  Apropos \Ap"ro*pos`\ ([a^]p"r[-o]*p[=o]`), a. & adv. [F. [`a]
     propos; [`a] (L. ad) + propos purpose, L. proposium plan,
     purpose, fr. proponere to propose. See {Propound}.]
     1. Opportunely or opportune; seasonably or seasonable.
        [1913 Webster]

              A tale extremely apropos.             --Pope.
        [1913 Webster]

     2. By the way; to the purpose; suitably to the place or
        subject; -- a word used to introduce an incidental
        observation, suited to the occasion, though not strictly
        belonging to the narration.
        [1913 Webster]

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

  apropos
      adv 1: at an opportune time; "your letter arrived apropos" [syn:
             {seasonably}, {timely}, {well-timed}, {apropos}]
      2: introducing a different topic; in point of fact;
         "incidentally, I won't go to the party" [syn: {by the way},
         {by the bye}, {incidentally}, {apropos}]
      adj 1: of an appropriate or pertinent nature [ant: {malapropos}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also in French version of most software, the "About" item is translated by "À propos" which is a fairly accurate translation.

Answer (score 1):

In English apropos is a word that means appropriate or at an opportune time.

Comment: Good job, Watson.

Answer (score -2):

In computing, apropos is a command to search the manual pages files in Unix and Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: I think that is obvious here, considering he linked to the wikipedia article on it. Your answer is not valid to the question.